# import objects from the last frame of a rigid body simulation?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, append

Can I have 2 blend files, one with a rigid body of a bunch of objects falling into a bowl, bake that simulation, and in the second blend file import the bowl and objects from the first file with their locations from the last frame of the rigid body simulation?  In the second file I'm going to have a fluid simulation pour a liquid into the bowl, over the objects.

Answer (score 1):

If I export it to OBJ then import into a new file, that works. Before I posted my question I had tried exporting to Alembic because I thought it was better but it didn’t do what I wanted. I guess I needed the not-better and simpler OBJ format.